# How to know if update has been called in an instance? Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to be able to increment a field every time update is called in the instance. Is there a way to check? Sequelize

Comment: Maybe you can use hooks?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]